# How to keep radio button value inside php variable without error

Tags: php, html, forms

Let me explain more in details what I am trying to do.

Okay so, I am doing a huge form to send in a particular e-mail. My problem right now is that only my radio buttons in my form show an error when the form is submit and return false. Here's an example of what I am talking about :

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $radio = $_POST['number'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];

    }

?>

<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="number" value="allo">
    <input type="radio" name="number" value="yo">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

So as you see, if the customer press on "submit" and didn't filled values inside of radio and input field, $name will show no error but $radio will show an error.

My Error :

Notice: Undefined index: number in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\preg.php on line 5

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: Sorry about that, Notice: Undefined index: number in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\preg.php on line 5

Comment: you need to check if it's set first..... `isset()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are getting is the server warning and not an actual error.
To avoid it you have flags that you can set to ignore warning, but this isn't a good practice.
I would suggest you to check if the form are set and handle them if not.

Code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $radio = (isset($_POST['number']) ? $_POST['number'] : "");
        $name = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "");
    }
?>
```

Edit: Of course, lets not forget, the better practice will be handle them against malicious code.

Comment: I can handle malicious code, thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @user3038607, You welcome, if you liked it, vote it as "Accepted answer".

Comment: By the way, Orel Eraki, I was wondering if htmlentities is necessary on a radio button, or select tag?

Answer (score 2):

You get that error because $_POST['number'] is not passed to the page.
You should set at least one of the radio buttons, and if you want to be sure of not getting an error even if the users modifies the page, you can check with an isset as others as wrote in the other answers.

If you were wondering why you didn't get any error from the name, that's because it contains the empty string "".

Check this code and view the source of the page to see what print_r writes in a formatted way

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $radio = $_POST['number'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];

    }
    print_r($_POST)
?>

<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="number" value="allo" checked="true">
    <input type="radio" name="number" value="yo">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['number']))
{
    $radio = $_POST['number'];
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `null`. [`isset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) already checks if it's not null though.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) $name = $_POST['name'];
```

but even better is

```
isset($_POST['name']) ? $name = $_POST['name'] : $name = '';
```